# What tools do I have for building a Cardano Dapp right now?

Tags: testnet, smart-contract

I am building a Dapp in Cardano and I want it to build NFTs even if it's not possible right now, **what tools can I use for it?**

I know that there is a testnet where I can run Plutus contract. **How can I access to it? Can I?**

If it's not a good idea to write the contracts an Dapps, **should I use testnet in a local PAB Plutus application back end, and wait till the testnet is available to everyone?** Or **would you recommend to do all what is possible with Cardano Cli?** as far as I know there is no way to running smart contracts using Cardano Cli, **is this true?**

Thank you so much, I am following Plutus pioneer courses but it's hard to know what can I bring to life right now, and how.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community! Thank you so much for contributing your question here and we hope to see much more of you in the future!!! I would recommend though, that you try to split your question up into more focused questions, or to at least re-structure this post a bit, since currently there's multiple questions being asked in one post, which is usually not the best idea in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 3):

It is very possible to create an NFT on Cardano since the very second native tokens were supported, which was back in January. I advise you to provide lasting power and permanence to your NFTs by adhering to the [CIP-721 metadata standard](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/blob/8b1f2f0900d81d6233e9805442c2b42aa1779d2d/CIP-NFTMetadataStandard.md), so blockchain explorers (and eventually other dApps) will be interoperable with the NFTs that you issue.

Cardano will be the PREMIER blockchain for NFTs, due to the fact that all native tokens are first class citizens on Cardano and it is trivial to create a forging transaction and issue NFTs. You can define the supply (rarity) right in the monetary policy of the forging transaction.

There is already a [thriving NFT community](https://cnft.io/) on Cardano.

To accomplish something similar on Ethereum you would need to create a ERC721 smart contract and program it to your needs. With Cardano, all you need is the Cardano wallet CLI and there is a [great tutorial](https://www.leewayhertz.com/create-nfts-on-cardano/) on how it works.

Now it is true that complex dApp logic with these NFTs won't be possible without smart contracts (swapping, auctioning off on DEXs etc.), but the act of creating an NFT on Cardano is as trivial as it could be!

Welcome aboard!

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, i will wait to see if anyone else can provide me a little more of insights regarding the testnet current state for making use of smarts contracts functionality, before accepting your answer.

Comment: Not NFT related, but SundaeSwap (DEX) completed the world's first swap using their smart contract deployed to the Cardano testnet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cz-EDAjG3vk

Comment: Thank you so much... I think maybe I can see if in Cardano client.. is possible to send a tx  tx with a script

Comment: I have my doubts about Cardano NFTs vs Etherium tokens, i belive there are more option to exploit in Etherium tokens die to the intrinsic nature of the smart contracts in them.. for example Royalities.